# a question on linear polynomial with matrix co-eficient

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix $M=A+\lambda B$ and given that $\exists c\ni \det(A+cB)\ne 0$
, put $A_1= A+cB$ then $M=A_1+(\lambda-c)B$ , then $A_1^{-1}M=I+(\lambda-c)A_1^{-1}B$, now by a similarity transformation we can reduce this matrix in the following form

$I+(\lambda-c)PJP^{-1}$(am I right here?), where $J$ is jordan form of the matrix $A_1^{-1}B$ and further $J=J_o+J_1$ where $J_o$ is the nilpotent part and $J_1$ is the diagonal( block diagonal) part with $\det J_1\ne 0$

now , what will be the simplest form of the final matrix after multiplying the diagonal part by $(I-cJ_o)^{-1}$?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: I haven't the book at hand, but you seem to have misunderstood Gantmacher's notations. $J$ is not $J_0+J_1$, but $J_0\oplus J_1$. That is, $J=\operatorname{diag}(J_0,J_1)$, where $J_0$ and $J_1$ are two smaller-sized matrices than $J$. If $B$ is singular, $J_1$ is void (i.e. it becomes the $0\times0$ empty matrix). The multiplication mentioned in the passage is performed solely on the first block ($J_0$). The second block ($J_1$) is left untouched.

Comment: @user1551 thank you very much for your comment and helping me out, I am not understanding the direct sum of two smaller matrix means, can you give me an example?

Comment: E.g. $J_0=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\ J_1=1$. Then $J_0\oplus J_1=\pmatrix{J_0\\ &J_1}=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1}$. You just append one block to the other on the diagonal.

Comment: thank you @user1551, so $I_2\oplus I_2= I_4$?

Comment: Yes. Apparently, the pair of brackets is just his way of denoting a direct sum. In modern notations, if $J_0$ is $r\times r$ and $J_1$ is $(n-r)\times(n-r)$, then what (4) means is that $I_n+(\lambda-c)(J_0\oplus J_1)=(I_r-cJ_0+\lambda J_0)\oplus(I_{n-r}-cJ_1+\lambda J_1)$.

Comment: thank you again! now are they multiplying $I+(\lambda-c)J_1$  by $(I-cJ_0)^{-1}$? by the way their $E$ is mine $I$

Comment: No. What he does is to multiply $(I_r-cJ_0+\lambda J_0)$ (the **first** diagonal block) by $(I_r-cJ_0)^{-1}$. The second diagonal block is left untouched. And yes, his $E$s is our $I$s, although there are several $E$s with different dimensions here but he doesn't specify the dimensions clearly using subscripts.

Comment: can I write, $(I_r-cJ_0)^{-1}=I_r +c J_0+(cJ_0)^2+\dots+(c J_{k-1})^{k-1}$, If I assume degree of nlpotency as $k$?, could you please explain how they got that form after multiplying this?

Comment: Yes. Anyway we don't need this expansion. All we need is the fact that $(I_r-cJ_0)^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $J_0$ and hence it commutes with the nilpotent matrix $J_0$. It follows that $(I_r-cJ_0)^{-1}J_0$ is also nilpotent. That's why he says that *"Here the coefficient of $\lambda$ is a nilpotent matrix"*.